# Why does Response.Redirect does not take direct the browser to the correct domain?

Tags: iis-7, iis

I asked the below question on StackOverflow, and the recommendation was to ask this question in this forum.

I have a web application that is hosted on 2 different web servers and a server farm is configured to load balance requests to those 2 different server. All servers are running Windows 2008 R2.

I have a simple ASPX page (test.aspx):

```
<script language="c#" runat="server">
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com/gmail");
}
</script>
```

If I browse to `http://serverfarm/test.aspx` the browser will point me to `http://serverfarm/gmail`, but if I point to `http://server1/test.aspx` or `http://server2/test.aspx` the browser will take me to `http://www.google.com/gmail`.

Any idea what setting in IIS could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 word.  Caching.

Clear your browser cache, and possibly your loadbalancer cache... and you should be golden.  Alternatively... try browsing to the serverfarm with a bogus parameter.  Like: `http://serverfarm/test.aspx?bogus=123456` and if you need to refresh the page again... just change the bogus value.

Comment: You were spot on...  Turning caching on the Web Farm resolved the issue.  Thank you very very much!